# How do I programatically add a view into another view loaded from a XIB file?

Tags: ios, view, toolbar, photo

I have a XIB file (view) that has a toolbar and a view right below it, as illustrated in the image below:

[image: Desired View]

[You can also view the image here.](http://raphaeu.com/pergunta/voltar.jpg)

I am using the following PhotoScroller: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html

The problem is that the PhotoScroller is dynamically created into the method loadView and directly assigned to its own view. That makes the PhotoScroller fills up the entire screen, which is not what I want.

I want to be able to put the PhotoScroller only inside the view that is below the toolbar (that is, the view numbered 2 in the picture above).

I think I have to load the view that is inside the XIB file and assign the PhotoScroller to that view. However, I have no idea how to do that (or if that`s even the solution).

How could I do that?

PS: Even though the number 2 shows a list, it is not a list! It`s just a simple blank view (I just couldn`t find a better image to put here).

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing

```
self.viewPanels = pagingScrollView
```

try to do (this will work only if you also add viewPanels as a subview to self.view):

```
[self.viewPanels addSubview:pagingScrollView];
```

I think that you should also modify or override the implementation of `frameForPagingScrollView` that comes with the Apple sample:

```
- (CGRect)frameForPagingScrollView {
  CGRect frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
  frame.origin.x -= PADDING;
  frame.size.width += (2 * PADDING);
  return frame;
}
```

as you see, here the frame is pretty hardcoded respect to the screen size; in your case the frame will be shorter, so you should change the height also.

Comment: Humm, I don`t think I made myself clear enough. Let me try to ask in a more simply way, using only a ScrollView.

Let`s say I have a xib file with a toolBar and a View right bellow it. What I want to be able to do is to set that view (I mean just the view bellow the toolBar, not the whole window).

I want to be able to do something like this:

-(void) viewDidLoad{
    CGRect pagingScrollViewFrame = [self frameForPagingScrollView];
    pagingScrollView.delegate = self;
    self.viewPanels = pagingScrollView;
}

On the last line, the viewPanels view is the one that is located below the toolbar

Comment: The thing is that the last line doesn`t work. It compiles and runs ok, but the view bellow the toolbar (viewPanels) remains white (no scroll view is shown). The only way to make the code works is by replacing the last line by self.view = pagingScrollView. The problem is that, with this last approach, the ScrollView fills up the entire screen and gets rid of the toolbar.

Comment: That worked sergio! Thanks a million! I`m just curious though. Why is it that self.viewPanels = pagingScrollView doesn`t work?

Comment: Glad to hear it! it does not work because you have to distinguish among your ivars and the subviews; if you add a subview self.viewPanels to a view self.view, than change viewPanels, self.view is not modified at all, it still keeps the old view.